# Как добавить изображение к уже существующему массиву изображений на сервере? Xcode

Tags: xcode, сервер, swift, клиент-сервер

Здравствуйте! На данный момент есть класс, который отправляет от 1 до 11 параметров на сервер в `JSON` формате ( это текстовый параметр и от 0 до 10 параметров формата `NSNumber`). И класс построен так, что при изменение какого либо формата удаляются все данные которые уже есть на сервере и сохраняются новые, то есть идет полная перезапись. Это не страшно так то, как максимальный объем этих данных всего 2.7 килобайта. Задание гласит "Организовать как массив ссылок на изображения", и что нужно просто добавить массив изображений в текущий класс. Но возникают несколько проблем: 1 Если есть на сервере уже одно изображение, и мы просто добавляем еще одно, то получается идет перезапись уже двух изображений, а если их будет 10? То это сильный удар по трафику пользователя, плюс это не правильная конструкция взаимодействия сервера с приложением. 2 Во время перезаписи больше 5 изображений, получаю ошибку, что сервер не доступен. Я хочу отправлять конкретное изображение к уже существующему массиву изображений на сервере, и не перезаписывать их каждый раз. Так же присвоить к каждому изображению ID, что бы можно было удалять на сервере изображения из приложения. Я пробовал много различных вариантов, но не смог добиться желаемого результат.
Вот код текущего класса

```
public class AnswersDataServerEntity: DataSetEntity {
    static let DataSetName = "DataSetName"

    var id: String? = "0"
    var streetId: UInt = 0
    var streetName: String? = ""
    var answers: [AnswerServerEntity]? = []
    var documents: [DocumentServerEntity]? = []

    private func save()
    {
        let deleteCommand = DataSetCommand(dataSetAction: DeleteDataSetAction<AnswersDataServerEntity>(dataSetName: AnswersDataServerEntity.DataSetName, data: self)

        deleteCommand.executeWithSuccess(
            {  (commond) -> Void in
                self.add()
            },
            errorHandler: { (error) -> Void in
        })
    }

    private func add()
    {
        let command = DataSetCommand(dataSetAction: AddDataSetAction<AnswersDataServerEntity>(dataSetName: AnswersDataServerEntity.DataSetName, data: self)

        command.executeWithSuccess(
            { (command) -> Void in
                if let _command = command as? DataSetCommand<AnswersDataServerEntity> {
                    NSLog("\(_command.dataSetAction)")
                }
            },
            errorHandler: { (error) -> Void in
        })
    }

    static func saveSelected()
    {
        self.selected().save()
    }

    static private func selected() -> AnswersDataServerEntity
    {
        var result = AnswersDataServerEntity()
        if let selectedCountry = CountryEntity.selected(){
            for answer in AnswerEntity.userAnswers() {
                result.answers?.append(AnswerServerEntity(questionId: answer.questionId))
            }
        }
          for document in DocumentEntity.deserializeDocuments() {
        let documentImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: document.documentImageURL)
        if let _documentImage = documentImage {
            let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_documentImage, 1)
            if let _imageData = imageData {
                let imageString = _imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
                result.documents?.append(DocumentServerEntity(documentId: document.documentId, documentTitle: document.documentTitle, documentImageString: imageString))
            }
        }
    }
        return result
    }
}

public class AnswerServerEntity: DataSetEntity {
    var questionId: Int = 0

    convenience init (questionId: Int){
        self.init()
        self.questionId = questionId
    }
}

public class DocumentServerEntity: DataSetEntity {

    var documentId: Int = 0
    var documentTitle: String = ""
    var documentImageString: String! // this string will to need to decode in base64string that we can to send it as JSON

    convenience init(documentId: Int, documentTitle: String, documentImageString: String) {
        self.init()
        self.documentId = documentId
        self.documentTitle = documentTitle
        self.documentImageString = documentImageString
    }
}
```

Результат с сервера, чтобы было лучше понимание, что отправляется.

```
request: {
    "object" : "storage",
    "section" : "api",
    "method" : "addData",
    "data" : [
    {
    "answers" : [
    {
    "questionId" : 201
    },
    {
    "questionId" : 203
    },
    {
    "questionId" : 206
    },
    {
    "questionId" : 210
    }
    ],
    "documents" : [
    {
    "documentImageString" : "\/var\/mobile\/Containers\/Data\/Application\/DD6F8D10-1241-4119-9639-AB983B27CFA6\/Documents\/04DDA484-F257-43BC-A459-3BC7C6050D6F",
    "documentTitle" : "xcode",
    "documentId" : 0
}
],
"streetName" : "Молодежная",
"id" : "0",
"streetId" : 14
}
],
"token" : "**********************$$$$*$*$*$",
"dataSet" : "DataSetName"
}
```

**UPDATE**
Есть класс, в котором есть параметры, они написанны в самом вверху класса, потом во время изменения какого либо из 11 параметров, класс удаляет все параметры с сервера и записывает новые значения. Задание поставленно следующие "Необходимо сохранять документы на сервере, Организовать как массив ссылок на изображения", далее я пытался это как то реализовать, но узнал, что нужно добавить в этот класс массив сущностей изображений ( изображение, описание изображение). Но получается, если просто добавить в этот класс массив сущностей изображений, то при изменение хотябы одного параметра или добавления нового изображение, мы удаляем все данные и грузим новые, это не очень страшно если изображений 2 (  и то это как то ужасно выглядит), а если их будет 10, то получается мы каждый раз будем передовать огромное количество данных. Я пробовал различные методы API(api не open source, а компании) через которое приложение обшается с сервером, но не один из вариантов не увенчался успехом.

Comment: не понятно вообще ничего.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko добавил свой комментарий в вопрос в UPDATE, так как он превышал допустимое количество символов.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko класс писал не я, и я не могу изменять уже рабочие методы, да наверно это не к чему, но не понятно, как можно построить по другому логику, я делал много различных вариантов, например добавлял одну сущность изображения, но тогда все остальные данные будут пустые.

Comment: все равно ничего не понятно. у вас есть api. вы говорите, что он как то очень странно работает. если вы можете идентифицировать проблемы с api идите к тому, кто это написал и предлагайте как переписать нормально. если api не выполняет нужные вам функции - идите говорите что надо дописать. если api работает нормально, идите спрашивайте того, кто это писал, как по его мнению должен происходить нужный вам процесс.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была со стороны api, большое спасибо за помощь!